# Python Yowsup - Group Messages

Tags: python, asyncore, yowsup

I installed YowSup and configured it, when yowsup recieves a message from group it crashes, this is what i've got:
As i can see there's something with asyncore but i dont know what and why.
http://pastebin.com/raw/tuY7geWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing similar problem only for group messages, If you bypass axolotl layer for group messages then it might just do the trick:

I modified line 105 of yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer.py to:

if node.tag == "message" and node["type"] == "text" and node["to"] not in self.skipEncJids and not "-" in node["to"]: